# Settings a variable from an array does not work - "Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, socket.io, undefined

I have this chunk of code from a tutorial, most likely outdated:

```
setInterval(function() {
    for(var i in SOCKET_LIST) {
        var tpssocket = SOCKET_LIST[i];
        tpssocket.emit('playerPos', {
            x: tpssocket.x,
            y: tpssocket.y
        });
    }
}, 1000/20);
```

That would give an error:

```
tpssocket.emit('playerPos', {
          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined
```

I have also tried pre-declaring the variable and removing the "var" from the tpssocket defining.
However, it still errors.

This is the exact same code that the tutorial used.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why are you doing the `division` literally in the function call? Just write `50`.
2. I suspect that `<{x: int, y: int}>SOCKET_LIST[]` takes the following form. Where is socketList? I believe it is in an upper scope so it resides here as a `closure` so called form.
3. I would suggest debugging for sure but you can try:

```js
if(SOCKET_LIST && SOCKET_LIST.length) {

SOCKET_LIST.forEach((socket) => {
  if(socket) {
    socket.emit('playerPos', {
       x: socket.x,
       y: socket.y
     });
  }
})
}
```

Comment: Things have definitely changed since 2016, the code in that video doesn't work now. Unfortunately SOCKET_LIST.forEach is not a function, even though it is listed as a function. As is a lot of other things that should exist.

Comment: I thought `SOCKET_LIST` is a variable which `holds` a value of an `[]`, `Array`